# how to keep session alive after page refresh

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters, page-refresh

Please how do I keep the home session alive when a user refreshes the browser ?

Because after login, the home page session is alive. But when I refresh the browser, it takes me back to login page.

```
import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    /**
     *
     * @author Maxwell
     */
    @WebFilter(filterName = "sessionFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
    public class sessionFilter implements Filter {

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest req1 =(HttpServletRequest)request;
            HttpServletResponse res1 =(HttpServletResponse)response;

            String session = (String)req1.getSession().getAttribute("pnumber");
            String currentPath = req1.getRequestURL().toString();

            if(session != null)
            {
                if(currentPath.contains("login.xhtml"))
                {
                    res1.sendRedirect(req1.getContextPath()+"/home.xhtml");
                   System.out.println("it is nt empty");
                }
                else
                {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
                //System.out.println("it is nt empty");
            }
            else
            {
                if(currentPath.contains("home"))
                {
                    res1.sendRedirect(req1.getContextPath()+"/login.xhtml");
                    System.out.println("somefin is wrong");
                }
                else
                {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
                //System.out.println("somefin is wrong");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {

        }

    }
```

Please how do I keep the home session alive when a user refreshes the browser?

Because after login, the home page session is alive. But when I refresh the browser, it takes me back to login page.

Comment: There is **no** jsf in the code you posted, just a servlet filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any warning or error in the console when refreshing the page? Well, for session management in JSF, I'd do the following:

**1)** I'd use a ManagedBean @SessionScoped, where I'll keep the user info into a SessionMap once s/he has logged in:

```
public void login(){
  //your code
  if(validations){
     FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     fc.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("loggedUser", User);
     //User is the entity which contains the current user info.
     //You can use any data to keep in the SessionMap ;-)
  }
}
```

**2)** When the user clicks on *logout*, you have invalidate the session:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
fc.getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
```

**3)** Now if you want to validate the session when the user types the URL directly without logging in from the login page:

```
public void validateSession(){
   FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   User currentUser = (User) fc.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("loggedUser");
   if(currentUser==null){
      //shows a message 'Session has caducated'
      fc.getExternalContext().redirect("./login.xhtml");
   }
}
```

Then you just call the method before rendering the view:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{loginBean.validateSession()}" />
```

**4)** If you'd like to get the current user data from any managedBean, you have to get it from the SessionMap:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
User user = (User) fc.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("loggedUser");
```

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: thank you ;-), i have done all that . But when the user logs in and is on the user page, if he decides to refresh the browser, he is automatically redirected back to login page again. I still want the user to maintain the user page even after refreshing the browser